Why is the common mode current said to be equal in magnitude for both line and neutral when clearly the path impedances are different?
When I look at the current flow for common mode noise current, I don't see equal impedance between the two paths. I think the equality should be valid only if there are symmetrical paths.
Case 1:

In the above diagram, I see the current flow through -ve input line (neutral) haa a slightly lower impedance than the +ve path which has the additional impedance of Ci.
Case 2:

In the AC scenario, I see a significant difference in the impedance due to the presence of the rectifying diode.
The return current has to flow through the diode parasitic capacitance whereas the line current gets to free flow through the forward biased diode.

COMMON-mode current is common to all conductors, by definition.
If the conductors have different impedances, then any imbalance in currents that develops will be a differential-mode current.
